# Scatter Plot with X-Y axis

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am charting the values of the DISC personality test on a google chart.

Location on the X-axis is Influence - Compliance.

Location on the Y-axis is Dominance - Steadiness.

I've tried every combination of Data Ranges, Identifying X-Axis, Adding Labels, going through common errors - https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/common-errors-in-scatter-chart/

[image: Screenshot]

I cannot seem to get each person's score to populate correctly on the X-Y axis along with their names as the label.

The sheet is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aq8bCIDCpdW8XXnwDcd8bOAwH0KCPs5-a-6-saJITxg/edit#gid=499653271

Answer (score 0):

it would need to be like this:

[image: 0]

### __________________________________________________________

## UPDATE:

[image: 0]

Comment: The X-Axis in your example is the names. I am looking to have the X-Axis be Influence (positive values) and Compliance (Negative Values). The names would be the labeled data points similar to the infospired image: https://infoinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Incorrect-Data-Point-Labels-in-Scatter.png

Comment: not sure I see the difference between infoinspired picture and image from the answer - it's kind of the same logic

Comment: Sorry, wrong image: https://infoinspired.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Correct-Data-Point-Labels-in-Scatter.png

Comment: I was thinking something more like this. https://ibb.co/sJJ4gqp Each person has one dot that represents their score.